# How to auto accept android permissions

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am developing an app for internal use and it requires some permissions like camera, internet, etc.

In order to make everyone's life easier I am investigating the possibility of auto accepting all these permissions on runtime.

The app will not be published on Play Store and it will only be used by employees on company premises and with company devices, so there is no security risk involved here.

Any ideas? Is this even possible? Hackish solutions work too, doesn't really matter as long as the goal is achieved.

Comment: Have you seen: https://developers.google.com/android/work/requirements#42-runtime-permission-grant-state-management

Answer (score 1):

If you're using targetSdkVersion>=23 your app has to request the permissions 
If permissions are considered "normal" the system will immediately grant them upon app installation. Other permissions which are considered "dangerous", the user must explicitly grant your app access to them.

If you downgrade the targetSdkVersion to API level 21 , there would be no need to ask permissions , since they will granted during app installation, but still on android devices with OS versions >= 6.0 the user can go to app settings and disable them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can, and **this is why:**

If your permission is `normal permission` it will be auto-granted.

- If the device API level is <= 22 / targetSdkVersionis 22 or lower:

In that case, the user will be asked (by the system) in the install time to grant all the dangerous permissions for the app.

- If the device API level is > 22 and targetSdkVersion is above 22:

The user will not accept dangerous permissions at install time. You must ask the user to grant access to the dangerous permissions at runtime - when you do ask your user to give access to those permissions on run time he will see system dialog that asks him to accept or decline the permissions.

**I don't think that you can do what you want  and I think that your best solution is to just ask the users the wanted permissions.**